# Como adicionar option para um select por Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Estou tentando criar um `select` que recebe suas opções via JavaScript ou jQuery, os dados estão armazenado em um array.

Exemplo:

```js
for (i = 0; i <= cidades.length; i++) {
    $('select').append('<option>' + cidades[i] + '</option>');
}
```

Mas eles não aparecem. o `append()` não funciona nesse caso ?

Comment: A única coisa que tem de errado no seu código é que i tem que ser menor (<) que cidades.length e não menor ou igual (<=). Mas isso não impediria de adicionar as opções ao seu select. Verifique se realmente tem dados adicionados ao array, se realmente existe um select na página e se a biblioteca jQuery realmente carregou. Sugiro também verificar se o console do navegador (F12) mostra algum erro, e se sim copie e adicione na sua pergunta.

Answer (score 3):

O `for` descrito na pergunta irá funciona, você também poderia fazer conforme o código abaixo:

```
var cidades = [
    'São Paulo',
    'Rio de Janeiro',
    'Bahia'];

cidades.forEach(function(item){
    $('select').append('<option>' + item + '</option>');
});
```

Segue o [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/zad75qhk/).

Ou pode fazer assim se quiser colocar o value de uma maneira melhor.

```
$('select').append($('<option>', {
    value: item,
    text: item
}));
```

Comment: mas dessa forma, como é possível alterar ou criar o "value" ?

Comment: @Dr.G você pode passar o value dentro do append `$('select').append('<option value="+ item +">' + item + '</option>');`

Comment: Editei a resposta e adicionei um exemplo com o value :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var cidades = [
    'São Paulo',
    'Rio de Janeiro',
    'Porto Alegre'];


cidades.forEach(function(item){
    addOption(item)
});

function addOption(valor) {
    var option = new Option(valor, valor);
    var select = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    select.add(option);
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" size="8">
    <option>Montenegro</option>
</select>

<button type="button" onclick="addOption('teste')">Insert option</button>
```

Voce pode usar seu:

```
for (i = 0; i <= cidades.length; i++) {
    $('select').append('<option>' + cidades[i] + '</option>');
}
```

Da seguinte forma:

```
for (i = 0; i <= cidades.length; i++) {
    addOption( cidades[i] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Usando a função `map` e a `atribuição via desestruturação`:**

```js
//Array normal:
var cidades = [
  'São Paulo',
  'Rio de Janeiro',
  'Bahia'
];

cidades.map(item => {
  $('#select1').append('<option>' + item + '</option>')
});

//Com objetos:

cidades = [{
    id: 1001,
    nome_cidade: 'São Paulo'
  },
  {
    id: 1002,
    nome_cidade: 'Rio de Janeiro'
  },
  {
    id: 1003,
    nome_cidade: 'Bahia'
  }
];

//Usando a função map e desestruturação de javascript:
//Isto aqui é muio maaaaaaaaaaaaassa!
cidades.map(({
  id,
  nome_cidade
}) => {
  $('#select2').append(`<option value='${id}'>${nome_cidade}</option>`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>Select 1 Demo (normal)</h3>
<select id="select1"></select>

<h3>Select 2 Demo (Usando Atribuição via desestruturação (destructuring assignment))</h3>
<select id="select2"></select>
```

**REFERÊNCIA:**

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Atribuicao_via_desestruturacao
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score -1):

uma forma que fiz aqui no trabalho e funcionou bem:

```
 $("#Tabelaexemplo option").first().html('NÃO DEFINIDO');
```

Eu tenho uma tabela que é montada através de um `populate`, depois que este populate é montado, eu precisava adicionar a opção não definido.

Funcionou perfeitamente