# Como permitir que o usuário adicione uma nova opção num <select>?

Tags: javascript, html, select

Preciso montar um select onde o usuário possa adicionar novas opções, então preciso que o select permita digitação e um botão ao lado dele faria chamaria a função para incluir na lista. 
Como posso fazer isso? 
Tenho apenas o select básico com o link que deveria funcionar como botão:

```
<select class="tags" name="abrangencia" style="width: 300px;">
    <option value="">opt 1</option>
    <option value="">opt 2</option>
    <option value="">opt 3</option>
    <option value="">opt 4</option>
</select>
<a>
   <img style="height: 38px; margin: -10px;" src="imagens/campanha/botao-mais.jpg">
</a>
```

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92187/como-adicionar-option-para-um-select-por-jquery-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer assim, eu aqui verifico se existe alguma coisa digitada para que não adicione uma `<option>` sem texto:

```js
var input_ele = document.getElementById('new-opt');
var add_btn = document.getElementById('add-btn');
var sel_opts = document.getElementById('sel-opts');
var input_val;
add_btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  input_val = input_ele.value;
  if(input_val.trim() != '') {
    sel_opts.innerHTML += '<option>' +input_val+ '</option>';
    input_ele.value = '';
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="new-opt"/>
<button id="add-btn">Adicionar opção</button>
<select id="sel-opts">
  <option>Eu já existo</option>
</select>
```

Com [datalist](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist) ficaria:

```js
var input_ele = document.getElementById('new-opt');
var add_btn = document.getElementById('add-btn');
var sel_opts = document.getElementById('sel-opts');
var input_val;
add_btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  input_val = input_ele.value;
  if(input_val.trim() != '') {
    sel_opts.innerHTML += '<option>' +input_val+ '</option>';
    input_ele.value = '';
  }
});
```

```html
<input list="sel-opts" id="new-opt"/>
<button id="add-btn">Adicionar opção</button>
<datalist id="sel-opts">
  <option>Eu já existo</option>
</datalist>
```

**Atenção**, como explicado no link essa ultima alternativa não funciona em IE <= v9 nem no safari

Comment: muito bom! mas existe algum jeito de tornar a própria combo box digitável sem precisar de outro input do tipo text?

Comment: @rayraisemeup, o que é o combo box, podes mostrar que elemento html é esse sff

Comment: combo box é o mesmo que <select>.. a caixa de seleção com uma seta que ao clicar mostre as opções. Tem como tornar esse elemento digitável?

Comment: Acrescentei uma alternativa @rayraisemeup, pode ser isso?

Comment: Sim! Funciona muito bem, obrigado!